# Problemas al configurar FreeTDS OS Capitan

Tags: sql-server, macos

Estoy intentando conectarme a un servidor *SQL* desde una máquina con *OS X*, el *Capitan* por medio de *FreeTDS*. Realicé la instalación con `brew uninstall freetds`, hice los cambios en mi archivo `/usr/local/Cellar/freetds/1.00.24/etc/freetds.conf` y hasta el momento obtengo el siguiente error:

> Error 20009 (severity 9): Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist OS error 60, "Operation timed out".
>
> There was a problem connecting to the server.

Luego, tras ejecutar `tsql -C`, obtuve el siguiente resultado:

> Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
>
> Version: **freetds v0.91**
> freetds.conf directory: **/usr/local/php5/etc**
> MS db-lib source compatibility: **yes**
> Sybase binary compatibility: **no**
> Thread safety: **yes**
> iconv library: **yes**
> TDS version: **5.0**
> iODBC: **no**
> unixodbc: **no**
> SSPI "trusted" logins: **no**
> Kerberos: **no**

Y me di cuenta que tenía dos archivos `freetds.conf`. Quiero desinstalar *FreeTDS* y volverlo a instalar, ya ejecuté `brew uninstall freetds` y borré todos los archivos `freetds.conf`, pero sigo obteniendo la misma respuesta al ejecutar `tsql -C`.

No sé si tenga algo que ver que tengo instalada la librería ***pdo_lib***.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: SQL Server trabaja con dos modos de autenticación 1) Windows Authentication (esto significa que toma las credenciales actuales, lo cual no creo que sea el caso) y 2)Usuario y Contraseña (o ambos si así se desea). Revisa que esta parte se tenga bien configurada, así como tambien SQL Server se conecta por medio del puerto 1433 (por default, aunqe se puede cambiar y configurar el deseado) y de primera instancia que de la computadora donde deseas conectarte tengas conexión directa al servidor de SQL Server, intenta ejecutando el comando en la consola: `telnet NombreServidorSQLServer 1433`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. No creo que sea problema de la configuración o los accesos, ya que una compañera siguió los mismos paso y pudo conectarse sin problemas. Yo incluso puedo conectarme con Valentina Studio, pero si intento acceder desde la terminal o desde php me sale el error que describo arriba.

Comment: Porque no instalas mejor el driver oficial? https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/tree/dev#install-unix